# why there is an error in line 15 while accessing a field from firebase in my flutter chat app

Tags: firebase, flutter

my problem is in 15th line while accecing data['author_id'] but android studio says

> error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. (undefined_operator at [shaheb_chats] lib\src\widgets\message_wall.dart:23)

```
 class MessageWall extends StatelessWidget {

  final List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> messages;
  


  const MessageWall({Key key,this.messages}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: messages.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index){
        final data =  messages[index].data();
        final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
        if(user != null && user.uid == data["author_id"]){
          return ChatMessage(
            index: index,
            data: data,
          );
        }
        return ChatMessageOther(
          index: index,
          data: data,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The messages List is empty, can you provide the code on how you push messages inside the list

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you call to `data()` returns an object, while you expect it to return a map.

A quick way to cast the type is:

```
final data =  messages[index].data() as Map;
```

This error is caused by a change in version 2.0 of the Firestore plugin, and I recommend reading the documentation about [migrating to cloud_firestore 2](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/2.0.0_migration).